# Run function in separate folder

Tags: python

In my project folder I have two directories: `classes` and `fonts`.
The `fonts` directory contains my game's fonts' .ttf and related files (like special letter properties and widths). For example my `item` font has an associated `item.ttf` file and an `item.widths` file.

Now I would like to add another file for each font that contains a function related to rendering, so each font may have its own outline style or a glow effect or whatever that would be handled by code in this file.

Is there a way for me call a function from these files from within the `classes` folder without having to reorganize my folder structure? Can I call, for example, a function in `fonts/item_render.py` from within `classes/text.py`?

Comment: Is [`os.chroot(path)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chroot) what you're looking for?

Comment: 1) You can add `fonts` to syspath from whatever loads your `classes` package. 2) Make `fonts` and `classes` into sub-packages of your game package, then just do `from .. import fonts.blah`. 3) Avoid mixing code and data. Why not just put the code into classes?

Comment: Sam, it says that it's not available on Windows, so even if it were a solution I couldn't use it. Thanks for trying to help though. @MadPhysicist Thanks for the syspath pointer, that worked just fine. To answer 3, I'm just really used to organizing files like this from other projects where it couldn't be helped. Feels cleaner to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Following what Mad Physicist said, editing `sys.path` to include the project directory works fine, like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Path\\to\\Project\\')
import fonts
```

Same code works for modules anywhere else by adding their respective paths as well.

Answered this myself so I can mark it as such.

Comment: It works and there are several similar answers on SO. But it is not considered good practice to mess with python path this way (might lead to side effects at some point?). The proper way to solve your case is to make a complete python project structure (including a setup.py), that you can install as developer (i.e. via `python setup.py develop`), preferably from inside a venv. When this is done, your project's path belongs to your python path (in your venv) and you won't have problems to import anything from your project anymore.